# How to handle API requests when user locks device

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am working on a Xamarin iOS project. During my testing, I have found that if I perform a delete action, and lock the device while the task is executing, the app crashes. What is the proper way to prevent this from occurring?

```
// DeleteItem calls the api
bool success = await ViewModel.DeleteItem(itemToDelete);

if (success)
{                
    ViewController.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
}
else
{
    DisplayErrorMessage("An error encountered.");
}
```

Edit:
Upon looking at the device log, this is the error that occurred:
[image]

Comment: What is the crash?

Comment: That's part of the problem, I can't replicate it on the simulator, only when I test with my phone disconnected from the computer.

Comment: There should still be a crashlog available when you connect your device to Xcode.  Use the devices and simulators window and check the device logs.

Comment: @bschweer There will be a complete crash report in the device log (if the app is actually being terminated by iOS)